# When doing calculations with TSFC of multiple engines, do we add all TSFCs together?

Tags: propulsion, engineering, aerospace

I'm doing an assignment at the moment where I need to evaluate FOMs based off some characteristics of an aircraft. One of the parameters I need to evaluate is the best milage, which I'm doing like so:

[image]

For this particular aircraft, the TSFC (c) for each engine is 0.65lb/hr/lb. Do I substitute this into the equation I've attached or do I need to consider the second engine as well? So, would c = 0.65 + 0.65 = 1.3? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but everyone seems to be assuming c = 0.65 and I don't understand why when we have two engines.

Comment: If both engines burn the same amount of fuel then you need only one number. Obviously that single number will be scaled according to the total thrust and the total flown time.

Comment: **lb/hr/lb** is a hilarious unit. I strongly recommend to use **lbf** ([pound-force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force))) for thrust to avoid confusion. Or even better, use SI units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thrust-specific fuel consumption (TSFC) is a measure of how efficient an engine is. It tells you what fuel flow rate is required to generate a certain amount of thrust.

If you have two engines, they will have twice the fuel flow rate, but also generate twice as much thrust. So the ratio does not change:

$$ \text{TSFC} = \frac{\text{fuel flow rate}}{\text{thrust}} \; \rightarrow \; \frac{2 \times \text{fuel flow rate}}{2 \times \text{thrust}} = \text{TSFC} $$

So you can use the same TSFC regardless of how many engines you have.

However, keep in mind that the TSFC of a typical jet engine depends on the engine RPM (N1) and other factors (like speed). Running one engine at maxmimum thrust will not result in the same TSFC as running two engines at half thrust because they will run at a different N1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense.